# In C#, how do I store the amount of times random numbers equal certain sums in an array?

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, oop, random

I'm writing a program that rolls _ amounts of _ sided dice _ times as specified by the user. This is a project with set requirements such as the class structure and the fact I have to use an **array** to show my results. The results are supposed to display each total I could possibly get and the amount of times I got each total after rolling for the specified amount of times.

I've written my attempt at this and fully expected it to work, but of course it did not. 
Rolling 1,000 times and rolling 2 dice with 6 sides, here are my results:

```
4) 4
6) 4
8) 4
10) 4
12) 4
```

I'd expect something like:

```
2) 85
3) 83
4) 84
5) 82
... until 12
```

The sum doesn't start at 2 it starts at 4, it rolls 20 times instead of 1,000, and all the values are the same. Any idea what could be wrong?

Here's my code:

```
    private int[] myTotals;
    private int possibleTotal = 2;
    private int arrayLocation = 0;
    private int myNumberOfDice;
    private string results = "";
    private static Random diceGenerator = new Random();

    public DiceFactory()
    {

    }

    public void rollDice(int numberOfRolls, int numberOfSides, int numberOfDice)
    {
        myNumberOfDice = numberOfDice;

        myTotals = new int[numberOfRolls];

        arrayLocation = possibleTotal - 2;

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRolls; i++) {
            myTotals[arrayLocation] = diceGenerator.Next(1, numberOfSides + 1);
            myTotals[arrayLocation]++;
        }

        while (possibleTotal <= numberOfSides * myNumberOfDice)
        {
            results += (possibleTotal) + ") " + myTotals[arrayLocation] + "\r\n";
            possibleTotal++;
        }
    }

    public string getResults()
    {

        return results;
    }

}
```

Comment: Please read code aloud to your favorite [rubber duck](https://rubberduckdebugging.com/) to see if it makes sense (usage of `myTotals[arrayLocation]` is very confusing). Also some clarification of why `possibleTotal += 2;` would help... Overall [edit] of the question with real [MCVE] - including expected values of the array and how do you call that method - would help. Also clarify why post tagged with "OOP" when there is no real object-oriented code shown... So far this question is unlikely to help future visitors...

Comment: Also have you tried debugging your code? It helps a lot to step through every line and think about what you expect all the values to be before and after that line: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugging-absolute-beginners?view=vs-2019

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I added an example of what I'd expect as a result, thanks for the suggestions. `possibleTotal += 2;` is because this counts by 2s. That's pretty much a placeholder for now because it's assuming you have 2 dice.  I tagged OOP because this is an assignment for a class where we're learning object oriented programming and there's other classes in the program for the user interface and stuff that's object oriented. I guess I don't really need the tag.

Comment: @Knoop I did, it actually got me to this point. Trust me, it was even worse before lol.

Comment: Why do you think "3" is _not_ a possible total when throwing 2 dice with 6 sides each? You also realize your `arrayLocation` will _always_ be and stay = 0 ?

Comment: @Fildor oh, you're right, I just facepalmed really hard. I was thinking of the fact it had to **start** on 2. I guess that's a big issue lol. And why would my arrayLocation start at 0?

Comment: Ok fair enough, though looking at all the values at every breakpoint should give you huge clues (you're creating an array for 1000 entries and only manipulating the entry at index 0). Anyway you seem to be mixing 2 things. You want to count how often each possible roll occurs (for 2 dice this is only 2-12, so 11 possibilities). You want something like `myTotals = new int[11];` And in that array count when a total occurs. Keep in mind that for every "roll" you need to roll both dice to get the total so you'll end up with another loop inside that loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`arrayLocation` gets set to 4 (`6 - 2`) at the beginning of your method, and doesn't change as you go through either your rolling loop or your result-building loop. That explains why you're seeing the value `4` for all your outputs.

I'd suggest sticking with a simple `for` loop for your result-building loop:

```
for (int i = 2; i <= numberOfSides * myNumberOfDice; i++)
{
    results += (i) + ") " + myTotals[i] + "\r\n";
}
```

That isn't your only problem. You'll need to figure out how to add up the results from rolling multiple dice. (Your code doesn't currently use `myNumberOfDice` in the rolling loop.) Definitely learn to use your debugger and understand what you *think* should be in each variable at each step of the way, and compare it with what actually shows up each step of the way. Breaking complex things down into small, verifiable steps is the essence of software development.

Comment: _"arrayLocation gets set to 4 (6 - 2) at the beginning of your method"_ Are you sure about that? `possibleTotal` is initialized with 2, so it's 2-2 = 0 ...

Comment: Ah, yep, you're right. The `4` is just coming from the random generation, plus one due to the `++`. https://xkcd.com/221/